# echo in php code is causing problems

Tags: php, wordpress

The `echo` in the last line seems to be causing problems. However I can't take it out or it'll just print the line directly. How can I rewrite that part? Also, is there anything else wrong with the way the other php functions are written?

```
$output .= "
            <script src='http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'></script>
            <a href='http://twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button'
                data-url='". the_permalink() ."'
                data-via='username'
                data-text='". the_title() ."'
                data-count='horizontal'>Tweet
            </a>
            <iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=". echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)) ."&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=90&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' allowTransparency='true' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:20px;'></iframe>'";
```

Comment: What's with the extra single-quote at the end of the last line before the double quotes? What are these "problems" you're referring to? `My car is making a weird noise. -- Oh it must be engine.`

Comment: Why are you concatenating an echo? Either remove the `echo`, or change the period just before it to a semicolon (`;`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the "echo", you don't need it in a string concatenation:

```
$output .= "
        <script src='http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'></script>
        <a href='http://twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button'
            data-url='". the_permalink() ."'
            data-via='username'
            data-text='". the_title() ."'
            data-count='horizontal'>Tweet
        </a>
        <iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=". urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)) ."&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=90&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' allowTransparency='true' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:20px;'></iframe>'";
```

Answer (score 1):

`echo` does not belong in the middle of a string.  It doesn't return anything so it doesn't make sense to have it in the middle of a concatenation.

The concatenation you are doing is very long and I believe has a few mistakes.

There is an extra single quote at the end.

The url you are constructing for the iframe has you both doing a urlencode but also has you manually escaping ampersands.

A much better way of constructing a url is with: `http_build_query` and let the system put it together for you. Link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php It is almost always better to let the system put the url together for you.  Since it is in the middle of a bunch of html, you can then run `htmlentities` on the whole thing: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php  That will make it appropriate to use inside of html.

There is no way of determining if the other functions are incorrect unless you put up the code for them.  If they always return strings, you're fine.

Don't be afraid of breaking up your code into multiple chunks if it's getting complicated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an additional ' (apostrophe) at the end of your output.

```
</iframe>'
```